# Call PHP Function in jQuery (var)

Tags: php, jquery, function

I'm facing a small problem that I can't solve by myself.

I have this php function:

```
function intervalo_manha(){
    $que="select id_intervalo,data_15
          from intervalo_manha
          order by id_intervalo";
        $re=mysql_query($que);
        $object.="<select>";
        $object.="<option></option>";
    while(list($id_intervalo, $data_15)=mysql_fetch_row($re))
    {
       $object.= "<option value=\"".$id_intervalo."\">".$data_15."</option>"; 
    }
        $object.="</select>";
return $object;
}
```

This function return a select with information from database.

I also have this js function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              var destTable = $("#dataTable");
              $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
               var newRow = $("<tr style='margin-left:-60px'><td><INPUT type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td><td><INPUT type='text' name='txt[]' id='txt'/></td><td></td></tr>");
               $("#dataTable").append(newRow);
                newRow.find('input').autocomplete("get_cols_name.php", {
                    width: 260,
                    matchContains: true,
                    selectFirst: false
                    });
                });
            });
```

This one will add a new row to my table, and for each new input will "activate" autocomplete. What I want to do is, instead of this:

```
var newRow = $("<tr style='margin-left:-60px'><td><INPUT type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td><td><INPUT type='text' name='txt[]' id='txt'/></td><td></td></tr>");
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
var newRow = $("<tr style='margin-left:-60px'><td><INPUT type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td><td><INPUT type='text' name='txt[]' id='txt'/></td><td><?php echo intervalo_manha(); ?></td></tr>");
```

Calling php function directly will return nothing, and I can't do anything. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: are all codes inside one php file?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same page. I basically want to output my php function inside the variable declared in jQuery.

I dunno if that's possible, but doing the way I said in the post, I can't do what I want.

Comment: You have to be careful with your wording. You cannot call PHP functions from JS, but I think that is not what you want to do anyway (but your title suggests it). What you do is, you create the HTML page through PHP and in this process a PHP function is called, that generates some HTML and the result of this is injected into the final HTML page.

Comment: In your function, you don't connect to a database. Do you connect to a database somewhere in your script? If not you should get a warning. Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Hi again Felix,

Actually what I wanted is calling a PHP function inside the js function. I've searched and it seems that is not possible, like you mentioned.

What I want it, when adding a new row with my js function, it will add an input and a select that got values from database. This select is the output of php function.

Yes Felix, I have a connection string. The way I posted the topic, in the 1st post, I can add a new row and user autocomplete without any problems.

The problem is adding a select drop downlist (using DB values) to the html dynamically created.

Comment: If I can't call php function directly from js, how can I solve this. I want to keep the autocomplete feature too. I already tried several approaches, but haven't succeed till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a friend's help.

Basically what we've done.

We create a div with the "php echo":

```
<div id="intervalo-manha"><?php echo intervalo_manha(); ?></div>
```

Then we've hiden it with css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #intervalo-manha {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

After this we just called the div at jQuery function:

```
var newRow = $("<tr style='margin-left:-60px'>...<td>" + $("#intervalo-manha").html() + "</td></tr>");
```

I never thought that it could be so easier. :)

Thank you for everyone who gave me tips and suggestions.

regards

Comment: Probably we could do it in a cleaner way. It works and that's the important thing.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, because you execute your code inside **$(document).ready**.
This means php is already done and can't be executed after $(document).ready (thats because php is server-side only).
Either you will have to use ajax or you will have to do the php function call before calling $(document).ready and put it into a variable:

```
var php_function_result = "<?php echo intervalo_manha(); ?>";

$(document).ready(function() {
...
// use php_function_result here
...
}
```

Comment: My php function is done before calling the "js" function. I'll give a try to your approach.

Thank you

Comment: Tried your suggestion without success. After adding the var, my add new row button doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The HTML page is created by PHP so it is no problem to inject the return value from the PHP function. This has nothing to do with `$(document).ready()`. For PHP, this is just text.

Comment: @l3gion: This was more a comment to Thariama but you are welcome ;)

Comment: @I3legion: did you check if your function actually returns a non-empty string?

Comment: @Thariama, php function return a select with info from DB. Js function, create a new row.

Can you be more specific? Thank you.

Comment: @I3legion: i know, what about using $("#dataTable").innerHTML="<?php echo intervalo_manha(); ?>";

Comment: @Thariama, I can't do that. If I add that code into my function the Button to add a new row won't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

if all the codes are on the same page, try

```
echo "var newRow = $(\"<tr style='margin-left:-60px'><td><INPUT type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td><td><INPUT type='text' name='txt[]' id='txt'/></td><td>";
echo intervalo_manha();
echo "</td></tr>\");";
```

Comment: Thank you Reigel for your answer.

I already tried that approach but it didn't worked. Now I can't even add a new row in my table.

Answer (score 1):

You are using $().autocomplete(); to get_coll_name.php. $().autocomplete(); is most likely a jQuery UI or jQuery plugin that uses AJAX to call PHP. You will need to use AJAX to call PHP. You can not specify the method intervalo_manha(), you must specify a page. If you are using a framework, like Zend, this is easier as the framework allows you to specify methods in the call.

Comment: A little more help, or more details, would be appreciated. 

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this code: (Please add the html tag to complete the page sice I am not able to add it here)

```
<?php
```

function intervalo_manha(){
    return 'here is my data';

```
$que="select id_intervalo,data_15
      from intervalo_manha
      order by id_intervalo";
    $re=mysql_query($que);
    $object.="<select>";
    $object.="<option></option>";
while(list($id_intervalo, $data_15)=mysql_fetch_row($re))
{
   $object.= "<option value=\"".$id_intervalo."\">".$data_15."</option>"; 
}
    $object.="</select>";
```

return $object;
}

if($_GET['get_data']) {
    echo intervalo_manha();
    exit;
}

?>

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var destTable = $("#dataTable");
        $("#btnAdd").click(function() {

         var newRow = $("<tr style='margin-left:-60px'><td><INPUT type='checkbox' name='chk'/></td><td><INPUT type='text' name='txt[]' id='txt'/></td><td class='d_value'>...retrieving data...</td></tr>");
          $("#dataTable").append(newRow);

          //newRow.find('input').autocomplete("get_cols_name.php", {
           //   width: 260,
            //  matchContains: true,
             // selectFirst: false
              //});
             $.get('index.php?get_data=1', {}, function(data) {
              newRow.find('.d_value').html(data);
             });
         });
      });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click me" id="btnAdd" />
<table id="dataTable">

</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Tried your code jondm. Thanks.But, can you explain to me what should be the output?

Comment: I get what you wanted to do. Unfortunately, I couldn't solve my problem.

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be better to use ajax functions. Give to it name. Call php-script, and get data from output.

```
$.ajax(/*...*/);
```

?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I'll try it tomorrow, too tired today. :)