# i am not able read session which is defined in php in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am assigning the session in php now i am trying to read the session value in jquery in script tags please suggest me some method to read the session value in jquery with out using phptags ().

```
 <?php 
           if(!isset($_SESSION)){
               session_start();
           }
           $_SESSION['name'] = "testname";

           echo $_SESSION['name']; 
        ?> 
    //with this i will get name in session but how to read in 

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var name =  ???? //
                console.log(name);
            });
        </script>
how to r`enter code here`ead here with out php tags in script
```

Comment: You can do as `var name = '<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>'` but it is not good practice

Comment: ... name= '<?php echo $_SESSION['name'];  ?>';

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya You forget to surrond php tags with quotes. It will make JS errors.

Comment: @bub Quotes are missing around the php code.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Correct! Thanks

Comment: please tell the way with out php tags in jquery i am not interested in correction of the code what i gave there its just a example

Comment: i don't want read  var name = '<?php echo $session['name'] ?>'; like this soooo

Comment: Not interested in correction of the code? OK! Why do you ask us then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call PHP Function in jQuery (var)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948551/call-php-function-in-jquery-var)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the way to go around this issue but here is a quick hack to solve your issue:

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_SESSION)){
       session_start();
   }
   $_SESSION['name'] = "testname";
   echo $_SESSION['name']; 
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var name =  <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>;
        console.log("Name session variable is: " + name);
    });
</script>
```